# How to fix this complex color function?

Tags: complex

Currently, I am working of creating some tricky complex color function. I need the original values, not scaled, so I indicated `ColorFunctionScaling->False`, but result is incorrect.

Here is a simplified code for show the problem:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
ExceptNegAng[rad_] := If[rad < 0, 2 Pi + rad, rad];
ComplexColorFunction[argf_] := Hue[ExceptNegAng[argf]/(2 Pi)];
ComplexPlot[z, {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}, 
ColorFunction -> {ComplexColorFunction[#8] &, None}, 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

After run, we get:

[image]

Why is there a white(transparent) line on the plot?

How to fix `ComplexColorFunction`?

Comment: Your problem is the usage of Arg respectively the slot #8. From the doc: Arg[z] has a branch cut discontinuity in the complex z plane running from -\[Infinity] to 0. Cooler is PieChart[Table[Style[1, Hue[h, s, 1]], {s, 0, 1, .1}, {h, 0, 1, .1}]] from the documentation.  Exclusions->None is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the option `Exclusions -> None` to get

[image]